# Remove angular hashtag from laravel using .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

I have codeigniter .htaccess file like

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

# allow social media crawlers to work by redirecting them to a server-rendered static version on the page

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} (facebookexternalhit/[0-9]|Twitterbot|Pinterest|Google.*snippet)
RewriteRule eventApp/(\d*)$ [P]


# Required to allow direct-linking of pages so they can be processed by Angular
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*) /eventApp/index.html [NC,L]

</ifModule>
```

But i would like to remove hashtag from laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove the hash from the URL fragment, you only need to set angular to not add it, no need to modify `.htaccess` files. As such this answer proposes a cleaner solution to the problem presented.

In your angular base module, typically where you define your routes.

```
angular.module('app', [])
    .config([
        '$routeProvider', 
        '$locationProvider', 
        function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            // Hashtags no longer appear with this
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

            // Route definitions below
        }]);
```

You will also need to set the `base` header element in your HTML view. This is used by angular to determine the path it should use when constructing URL's. This example will use the root.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>Laravel</title>
    <base href="/" />
</head>
```

Comment: Is there no other way to specify the base to Angular? Using that tag breaks normal fragment links, e.g. `<a href="#bar">` on page with URL path `/foo/` doesn't go to `/foo/#bar`.

Comment: Yes, It is correct but if i can refresh my page it will display error like page not find in laravel. so i think we need to set .htaccess for it. So it working in CI like same as above rules i don't set it laravel. Please let us know about that if you know.

Comment: You can catch the routes in laravel, you don't need `.htaccess` modifications for this. `Route::any('{path?}', function() { return view("index"); })->where("path", ".+");` note the where on the end of the route, this will match all routes that are not defined and return the angular application.